# Is optional using @Inject for all constructors in Dagger2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Why some people uses @Inject for constructor of classes and some other did not use this annotation for constructor.
Is it optional to use this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not needed if you provide instance yourself:

```
//without @Inject
class SomeInstance contructor(...): SomeInstanceInterface{}

@Module
class Module{
  @Provides()
  fun provide():SomeInstanceInterface {
    return SomeInstance(...)
  }
}
```

But if you want that Dagger create instance for you, then you need to mark constructor with `@Inject` and ask `Dagger` to create instances:

```
@Module
class Module{
  @Provides()
  fun provide(inst: SomeInstance):SomeInstanceInterface = inst
}
```

or

```
@Component
interface Component{
  fun someInstance():SomeInstanceInterface
}
```